# useState - Array renderiza sempre vazio na primeira vez

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando fazer uma validação da variável `prods` com o `.length`, porém percebo que toda vez que este `useEffect` roda, ele retorna vazio antes da atualização da variável. Logo, qualquer tipo de validação com `length` se torna dispensável pois sempre cai neste primeiro vazio antes de atualizar os dados da váriavel.

```
const [prods, setProds] = useState([]);
const [prodsByCprod, setProdsByCprod] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  async function loadProdsByCprod() {
    const response = await api.get('/produtoByFk_Nfe');
    setProds(response.data);
  }

  loadProdsByCprod()
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  async function verificationCProd() {
    if (prods.length < 1) {
      alert("Você não tem produtos");
      history.push('/consulta');
    }
  }

  verificationCProd();
}, [prods]);
```

Mesmo o `prods` tendo dados, ele entra nesse `if`.

Eu conseguiria fazer esta validação de alguma outra forma? Visto que preciso que ela carregue para ver se a variável `prods` é alimentada e o usuário tem produtos, caso ao contrário, irei redirecioná-lo para outra página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `useEffect` é um hook que executa após primeira renderização do componente e após as renderizações subsequentes sempre que qualquer uma das dependências passadas for alterada. O que está acontecendo no seu caso é que, na primeira renderização do componente, o vetor `prods` está, de fato, vazio, então ele acaba sempre entrando nessa condição do `if`.

Para corrigir esse problema, use uma `ref` que armazene a informação de primeira renderização, como no código abaixo.

```js
const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (firstRenderRef.current) {
    firstRenderRef.current = false;
    return;
  }

  if (prods.length < 1) {
    alert("Você não tem produtos");
    history.push('/consulta');
  }
}, [prods]);
```

Se situações como essa acabarem ficando muito comuns, considere criar um hook personalizado para isso.

```js
function useStateUpdate(handler, deps) {
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      firstRenderRef.current = false;
      return;
    }

    return handler();
  }, deps);
}
```

Dessa forma, o seu código final ficaria com essa cara

```js
useStateUpdate(() => {
  if (prods.length < 1) {
    alert("Você não tem produtos");
    history.push('/consulta');
  }
}, [prods]);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela explicação.